# Complex exponential

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation, exponential-function

I know that the equation $e^{z}=-1$ has no solution had if been $z$ is a real number. So does the equation also has no solution when $z$ is complex?

Comment: $$-1=e^{(2n+1)\pi i}$$ where $n$ is an integer

Comment: $e^{i\pi}=-1$ for example. The set of all solutions to $e^z=-1$ follows.

Comment: What is this? This is another equation.

Comment: Okay, I got it now.

Comment: But how about $e^{z}=0$?

Comment: $\vert e^{z} \vert = e^{\Re(z)} > 0$

Comment: Since $e^ze^{-z}=e^0=1$, $e^z\ne0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On of the [most popular](https://www.google.de/search?q=euler%27s+identity&rls=en&safe=off&tbm=isch) formulas, if such a notion makes sense, is [Euler's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity), which states that $$e^{\pi i}=-1.$$

Also compare [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2491/math-se-swag-designs) ;)

Comment: But how is it solved? The equation $e^{z}=-1$.

Comment: I have solved it, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

My answer may be a little bit formal. Regarding the equation $e^{z}=-1$, note that :

- $\exp$ is a group homomorphism whose kernel is $2i\pi \mathbb{Z}$. (the kernel is the set of all complex numbers $z$ such that $e^{z}=1$).
- You know that $e^{i\pi} = -1$, which gives you a particular solution to $e^{z}=-1$.

These two facts give you that

$$ \left\{ z \in \mathbb{C}, \; e^{z}=-1 \right\} = i\pi + 2i\pi \mathbb{Z} $$

Answer (score 0):

Write $\;z=x+iy\;,\;\;x,y,\in\Bbb R\;$ , so by definition:

$$e^z=e^{x+iy}=e^xe^{iy}=e^x\left(\cos y +i\sin y\right)$$

It is now enough to use the periodicity of the trigonometric functions:

$$x=0\;,\;\;y=(2k+1)\pi\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\implies e^x=1\;,\;\;\sin y=0\;,\;\;\cos y=-1\;\ldots$$